# db2 command line processor & passwords containing '$'

Tags: linux, bash, db2

We are seeing a failure in the DB2 CLP when a password contains a $ character.  I've extracted the command into a simple bash script:

```
su - db2apm -c "db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using 'apm$2016'"
```

IBM documentations suggests that quoting the special characters should work:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21303153

But when I run this command:

```
[root@picard ~]# ./test.sh
+ su - db2apm -c 'db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using '\''apm016'\'''
attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR
PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

As you can see, '$2' is interpreted as a script variable with no value.  A variation on this, enclosing the whole command in single quotes:

```
su - db2apm -c 'db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using apm$2016'
```

looks like it should work, but doesn't:

```
[root@picard ~]# ./test.sh
+ su - db2apm -c 'db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using apm$2016'
attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR
PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

If I run the command manually, it also fails:

```
[root@picard ~]# su - db2apm -c 'db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using apm$2016'
attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR
PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

But if I split it, it works!

```
[root@picard ~]# su - db2apm
Last login: Tue Nov 29 11:17:56 EST 2016 on pts/3
[db2apm@picard ~]$ db2 -v 'attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using apm$2016'
attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using

   Instance Attachment Information

 Instance server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.6
 Authorization ID       = DB2APM
 Local instance alias   = APM_NODE
```

This feels like I'm a victim of some combination of bash, su and the DB2 CLP consuming the $ in some unexpected manner.  Any thoughts on how to get this to run?

Comment: the single-ticks are getting stripped off on their way from su to db2, so by the time db2 sees a bare $2016 to expand (to nothing); escape the `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you escape just the dollar sign, it should work (it did on my system when I just tried it):

```
su - db2apm -c "db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using 'apm\$2016'"
```

You can also try putting into its own script:

test.sh:

```
db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using \''apm$2016'\'
```

(I'm not sure if the quotes need to be escaped, if not, you can try the following: )

```
db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using 'apm$2016'
```

And then run it with:

```
su - db2apm test.sh
```

(Note no `-c`)

Hope this solves your problem!

Edit: Also, if this still doesn't help, you can try debugging it by putting an `echo` in front of the db2 call so that you can see what is being expanded and how:

```
su - db2apm -c "echo db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using 'apm\$2016'"
```

Comment: Thank you!  As you noted, escaping the dollar sign works.  I found that this also works:

`set -x
db2apm_pw='apm$2016'
su - db2apm -c "db2 -v attach to APM_NODE user db2apm using '${db2apm_pw}'"`